# Effective cache solution to have the newest data in React Native

Tags: javascript, caching, reactjs, react-native

### Goal

We have an app with different articles. I want to cache an article when the user has read it, but make sure that I display the latest data. I came up with this *hook*:

```
  React.useEffect(() => {
    (async function fetchArticle() {
      const articleURL = `${BASE_URL}/services/node/${route.params.nid}`;
      try {
        setLoading(true);
        const cached = await articleCache.get(route.params.nid);
        if (cached) {
          setArticle(JSON.parse(cached));

          axios(articleURL).then(({ data }) =>
            articleCache.set(route.params.nid, JSON.stringify(data)),
          );
        } else {
          const { data } = await axios(articleURL);

          await articleCache.set(route.params.nid, JSON.stringify(data));
          setArticle(data);
        }
      } catch (err) {
        setError(err);
      } finally {
        setLoading(false);
      }
    })();
  }, [route.params.nid]);
```

Does it make sense to fetch the data again every time? It seems kind of excessive to me, but I can't think of another away without the *API* being changed and returning some kind of timestamp instead of the full article to reduce the size of the request.

Is this way ok or can it be improved?

Comment: Not an answer but an observation: there's a whole layer in the browser that's designed to handle caching requests, including things like if-modified-since so that data does not have to be unnecessarily re-sent, and it's a shame that modern SPA style erases all of that.

Comment: Well it's a mobile app. I am not sure that applies. But yeah, I am always wondering whether caching works with something like _React_, and the answer seems to be no :-(